# Pointer seen by Visual Studio as a void**

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, pointers

something strange is happening to my code. I am using a library which is supposed to work perfectly (nglib from the open-source Netgen mesher). I can link and include everything, but I cannot use this library :

The object I want to use is `Ng_Mesh* mesh = Ng_NewMesh ();`

The Ng_NewMesh() method is :

```
   DLL_HEADER Ng_Mesh * Ng_NewMesh ()
   {
      Mesh * mesh = new Mesh;  
      mesh->AddFaceDescriptor (FaceDescriptor (1, 1, 0, 1));
      return (Ng_Mesh*) (void*) mesh;
   }
```

When I go to locals, it is seen as a `void**` referring to `*mesh` which is a `void*`. It is not `NULL` because I can add points and other stuff to this object, but with some functions, I get an exception :

> *`System.AccessViolationException`: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>
>   
>
>   at `nglib.Ng_GetPoint(Void** , Int32 , Double* )`
>
>   at `ForwardModelingPlugin.CustomMeshVol3D.tesselate(CustomMeshVol3D* )`*

`nglib.Ng_GetPoint` is supposed to have as arguments `(Ng_Mesh*, Int32, Double*)` which explains this exception.

I don't know why this casting is happening.

Comment: Did you check with the documentation if the constructed object (`mesh`) might have an unset dependency? ie. perhaps there is one field of the object you need to set to an instance of another object before you can call certain member functions?

Comment: `return (Ng_Mesh*) (void*) mesh;` -- Do you need the nasty casts? I get the impression that the cast to `void*` is only necessary because the compiler would complain if you casted a `Mesh*` directly to `Ng_Mesh*`? If so, would it complain for a valid reason, ie. are you sure a cast to `Ng_Mesh*` is valid? Or can you somehow do without the casts and just return a `Mesh*`?

Comment: I'll check this but I'm not sure, I am using some example included in the downloaded package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://netgen.sourcearchive.com/documentation/4.4-9/nglib_8h-source.html) it says:

```
/// Data type for NETGEN mesh
typedef void * Ng_Mesh;
```

therefore  `Ng_Mesh* mesh;` is the same as `void** mesh;`

Comment: Thanks, that's seems to be logical
@ Justin : Isn't that a/the problem?

Comment: @ChRtS: Yes, that would cause your memory corruption issue.

Comment: I highly doubt that the 'exotic' way of going from Mesh* to Ng_Mesh* is the cause of the memory corruption.
You should look for the usual suspects: using unallocated/deleted objects, writing out of objects bounds, not using/misusing your API way to create/destroy objects etc.